# How to use Math.float for a damage formula equation

Tags: javascript

I have found a guide for some damage formulas from FF9 and want to use them
in RMMV which uses Javascript.
Im bad at math and dont know how the Math.random and modulo
works or at least im doing something wrong.

I allways get 0 damage and im sure its because of wrong equation.
Since the Math.random gives a float from 0.00 to 1.00 I thought that would be the problem.
So I've tried to use a random number between 1 and 100 but that didnt helped.

```
Base   = Spell Power - Mag Def
Bonus  = Mag + Rnd MOD ([(Lvl + Mag) / 8] + 1)
Damage = Base * Bonus

SPELLPOWER - b.mdf * (a.mat + (Math.random() % ((a.level + a.mat) / 8) + 1))
16 - 2 * (16 + (Math.random() % ((1 + 16) / 8) + 1))

SPELLPOWER - b.mdf * (a.mat + ((Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) % ((a.level + a.mat) / 8) + 1))
16 - 2 * (16 + ((Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) % ((1 + 16) / 8) + 1))
```

Somehow this should actualy give a number higher then 0 with the stats i provide.

Comment: Can you give an example input object `a` and `b` and the expected output, so that we have code to run and debug?

Comment: a stands for user of the skill and b is the target.  Thats why i added numbers in the next line.

Comment: That doesn't really help - what is the object structure? Please include an example in your question

Comment: In the example the SPELLPOWER is 16 and b.mdf is also 16 a.level is 1.  The actual code is not both lines just the first is. The second is the example with actual numbers in it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Again, please post a full example input object `a` and `b`, so that we have a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

It was just some wrong set brackets which caused the trouble.

```
(SPELLPOWER - b.mdf) * (a.mat + Math.random() % (((a.level + a.mat) / 8) + 1))
```

This works perfectly fine now.